# Tailwind, opposite of visible to show and hide elements on mobile?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have the following snippet:

```
        <div>
            <table className="hidden sm:block w-full">
...
```

but when I expand the screen, the table doesn't take up the full width as the internet is suggesting me.

### With Code Above

[image]

### Desired Result

[image]

What is the opposite of `visible`? Everyone suggests `block`, but that seems like an odd default to me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like

```
 <table className="hidden sm:table w-full">
```

is the best approach here.